# Contour integral of continuous but not holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

This question was transferred here following Mathoverflow suggestions.

Let us consider two functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, both holomorphic on a domain $U$ (a simply connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$).
Thus, because of Cauchy's integral theorem, along any closed rectifiable path in $U$:
$$
\oint f(z)g(z)dz\ = 0
$$
Let us further assume both $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, and their respective derivatives, to be not identically zero on $U$. Considering that the product $f(z)g(\overline{z})$ is not holomorphic, in case $f(z)g(\overline{z})$ is continuous on $U$, could there still exist ***particular*** closed rectifiable paths in $U$ for which the line integral of $f(z)g(\overline{z})$ would be zero? or would such line integrals necessarily differ from zero for ***all*** closed rectifiable path in $U$? or are there specific theorems for special cases whereby that would be true?

Because $f(z)g(\overline{z})$ is not holomorphic, Morera's Theorem implies that the contour integral above cannot $= 0$ for all said closed rectifiable paths. I did realise that for not holomorphic integrands said integral would in general depend from the particular path, but I was unable to find theorems, and-or research papers, identifying in a more systematic way the additional conditions which such integrands and paths would need to satisfy in order to guarantee that the above integral $\neq 0$

It appears that starting from around 1930 there was some relevant research about the properties of what were called polygenic functions (is that definition still in use?), to which also said $f(z)g(\overline{z})$ would belong. I was able to find the following articles, but not much after that:

http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1930-032-02/S0002-9947-1930-1501534-9/S0002-9947-1930-1501534-9.pdf

http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183496499

NOTE: the additional condition $f(z)g(\overline{z})$ continuous on $U$ is specified as, depending on the domain $U$, it does not necessarily follow from the holomorphicity of $f(z)g(z)$. Just take the example: 
$$
g(z) = \frac{1}{z+\beta} \;\;\;\;\;\;\; \beta = 1+2i \;\;\;\; z \in U\;\;\;\;\;U=\left\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \; \Im(z)> 0 \right\}
$$ 
is continuous on $U$, but $g(\overline{z})$ is not continuous on $U$ (featuring a pole at $z=-1+2i$)

Comment: Of course the integral can vanish for particular paths. Take e.g. $f(z) = z^2$ and $g(z) = z$. The integral $\int_C f(z)g(\overline{z})\,dz$ vanishes for all circles $C$ with the origin as centre.

Comment: Yes, I did realise that there exist such possibilities. My aim is rather to verify whether it might be possible to identify some special conditions which, when satisfied by $f(z)g(\overline{z})$ and/or by the contour (especially by the contour), would result in the integral $\neq 0$. Morera's theorem can only reassure us that contours resulting in the integral $\neq 0$ must exist (otherwise the integrand would be holomorphic, which is not), but without revealing us which contours would correspond to that.

Comment: For most contours the integral will be nonzero. And if you happen to have a contour with a zero integral, making a small dent in that contour will get you a nonzero integral. By Stokes' theorem, making a small dent at $z_0$ will change the integral by approximately $\pm\frac{1}{2i} f(z_0)\cdot g'(\overline{z}_0)$ times the area between the contour with and without the dent.

Comment: That is a very interesting property, thanks.

Comment: What would you think about trying to hence approach my investigation the other way around? i.e. to identify whether those paths for which the integral = 0 would need to satisfy some additional general properties (when not satisfied ==> the answer I am seeking for).